# Extracting multi-valued attribute from LDAP groupOfUniqueNames

Tags: java, ldap

I'm trying to read all members who belong to group defined in LDAP as groupOfUniqueNames.

```
String url = "ldap://blah.blah.address:389/dc=foo,dc=bar";
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
String[] attrIDs = {"uniqueMember"};
SearchControls cons = new SearchControls();

Attributes answer = ctx.getAttributes("cn=testgroup", attrIDs);

NamingEnumeration e = answer.getAll();
while (e.hasMore()) {
    BasicAttribute attr = (BasicAttribute) e.next();
    System.out.println(attr.getID() + ": " + attr.get());
}
```

However, this code prints

```
uniqueMember:
```

as if it didn't read all values of unique member.

Using Apache Directory Studio I can see that this attribute has 3 values (one of which is empty). How can I access all of them?

If this matters I am using OpenLDAP.

Comment: Looks like LDAP only returned the empty value. I can't see anything wrong with your code, unless an exception is being swallowed. Is there any access-control on that member? You're using an anonymous connection with whatever minimal privileges are defined for that in slapd.conf.

Comment: No it is definitely not authorization issue. I managed to solve this problem using JLDAP.

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue when trying to get all members of a group (members are a multi valued field in the group entry). It will only return first member. Is this a bug in OpenLDAP? Java JNDI? I'd like to stick to JNDI and avoid JLDAP if possible. Thanks for any workarounds/ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using JLDAP

```
LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection();
conn.connect("blah.blah.address", 389);

String[] attrIDs = {"uniqueMember"};
LDAPSearchResults search = conn.search("dc=foo,dc=bar",
                                       LDAPConnection.SCOPE_ONE,
                                       "cn=testgroup", attrIDs, false);

while(search.hasMore()) {
    LDAPEntry entry = search.next();
    for (String string : entry.getAttribute("uniqueMember").getStringValueArray()) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```